# jquery datetimepicker plugin - how to initialise calendar/time select with the date/time from the field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I'm using this datetimepicker plugin for jquery: https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker

It all works fine, except that I want to change the date format from "YYYY/MM/DD" to "DD/MM/YYYY".  I've done this by passing

```
format:'d/m/Y H:mm',
```

in the options to initialise the datetime picker for the field.

That works, in that when I choose a date and time, it writes into the text field in that format, eg `2020/05/21 17:00`.

The problem occurs when the page loads and there is a date/time set in the field already:  this is in the same format as above, eg `2020/05/21 17:00` - the same format the plugin writes into the field.

When I click on the field and the calendar/timeselect appears, it's set to **NOW** rather than what was in the field.  It's like now that I changed the format, it can't read the date/time out of the field properly, and so doesn't initialize itself properly.  This all works fine when I stick with the default format ('Y/m/d H:mm')

The documentation is here:  https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

**EDIT** - here is a jsfiddle which demonstrates the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/Lphdnt20/

**EDIT 2** - trying @Kalimah's approach, below, it sort of works but it a bit broken - the datepicker (on the second input) looks like it has initialised at the right year and month, but the day isn't highlighted on the calendar and the minutes are all represented as "i":  see screengrab, which was taken on this page, after pressing the "Run code snippet" button. [image]

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: @Kalimah yes thanks I will try to do that.

Comment: @Kalimah added a jsfiddle, would you mind looking?  thanks

Comment: format:'d/m/Y H:mm' will give you day/month/year. It will givve you 21/05/2020 and not 2020/05/21. What is your goal format. Thus, the format will apply **only** to the values that will be parsed by the plugin and not to the value you inject in the value attribute of the input at page load. YOu have to parse the initial date to the same standard to have the same format

Comment: @LelioFaieta I have done that - have a look at the jsfiddle link, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug ([see here](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/issues/596)).

You have two ways to work around it. First one disable validate upon blur event by adding `validateOnBlur: false` to your options.

Or, you can validate using an external library like moment.js. The downside to this approach is that it applies globally to all date pickers. I could not find a way to make it specific to a single picker.

See more [here](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) about moment.js formatting options.

And this is a demo:

```js
/* Add this to enable moment.js formatting (or add your own formatter)*/
jQuery.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter({
  parseDate: function(date, format) {
    var d = moment(date, format);
    return d.isValid() ? d.toDate() : false;
  },
  formatDate: function(date, format) {
    return moment(date).format(format);
  }
});

$("#picker2").datetimepicker({
  step: 30,
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY' // Change to moment.js formatting options
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<input id="picker2" name="bar" size="30" style="width: 150px" type="text" value="25/02/2016 18:30">
```

If you decided to use the second option you need to apply format to each time you initialize the datepicker. See this example:

```js
jQuery.datetimepicker.setDateFormatter({
  parseDate: function(date, format) {
    var d = moment(date, format);
    return d.isValid() ? d.toDate() : false;
  },
  formatDate: function(date, format) {
    return moment(date).format(format);
  }
});

$("#picker1").datetimepicker({
  step: 30,
  format: 'YYYY/MM/DD H:mm',
  formatTime:'H:mm',
  formatDate:'YYYY/MM/DD'
});
//try to use different date format
$("#picker2").datetimepicker({
  step: 30,
  format: 'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm',
  formatTime: "H:mm",
  formatDate: "DD/MM/YYYY"
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<p>
  A text field with a date in datetimepicker's default format of "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm". Initialises correctly with the date/time from the input.
</p>
<input id="picker1" name="foo" size="30" style="width: 150px" type="text" value="2016/02/25 18:30">

<p>
  A text field with a date in "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" format (called 'd/m/Y H:m' in the datetimepicker options). The plugin will *write* the selected date and time into the field correctly, but it doesn't initialise itself properly from the time in the field:
  when it appears, the date and time picker are set to the **current** date/time, not the date/time from the input. Note that if you choose a time/date, it will write it into the input with the desired format, which suggests that the problem is not the
  'format' option itself.
</p>
<input id="picker2" name="bar" size="30" style="width: 150px" type="text" value="25/02/2016 18:30">
```

Comment: That bug you link to sounds different to my problem - the problem they describe is that when you click outside the input (blur event) the time changes.  That's not my issue.  My issue is that when the calendar appears, the date and time are set to **now** rather than the date and time that was already in the input, when I use `'d/m/Y H:m'` format.

Comment: The fiddle your provided shows that problem. The date changes when blur happens not during focus. My guess is that both issues are related and I think the code I provided solves your issue, does it not?

Comment: I tried your code in a new fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/eudLvhcy/ - it pulls in the right time and date now but the formatting is a bit broken in the datetime picker.  do i need to put the time format (eg "H:m" or similar) into  the format string too?

Comment: Yes. You need to put the formatting you want. You have to use the formatting of moment.js in the link that I provided.

Comment: even with the right format, the datepicker is a bit broken - the day isn't selected and the minutes show as "i": https://jsfiddle.net/eudLvhcy/2/

Comment: if you apply `setDateFormatter` you will need to apply format to each picker. In this case the default format needs to be added as `format: 'YYYY/MM/DD H:mm'`

Comment: but I want the date with the year last - even if I try `format:'DD/MM/YYYY H:mm'`, there are problems with the datetime picker:  would you mind checking this fiddle and seeing if i'be missed something? https://jsfiddle.net/8wrvpc36/2/

Comment: What I meant is if you use `setDateFormatter` then each time to initialize date picker on input you need to set a format. That's because the default format does not work with moment.js. I will update my answer

Comment: Thanks but i'm still seeing the same problem, including when i run your code directly.  I've put a screengrab in my answer, since I don't know how to do it in a comment.  Do you see something different to my screengrab when you run your snippet?

Comment: I get it now. I thought you were talking about the input not the time list inside the picker. In this case you need to add `formatTime: "H:mm"`. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: ah - yes, that looks perfect now - thanks!  I will mark it as correct, thanks for all of your time.